# Is it safe to delete an action group on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I tried setting up autoscale alerts on Azure App Services using this template: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/monitor-autoscale-alert. When deploying to Azure, it failed with an error that didn't explain what went wrong. So I gave up. I noticed that I have a hidden resource named `autoscaleActionGroup` of type `microsoft.insights/actiongroups` in my subscription. Not sure if it was there before trying to run the template. Is it safe to delete this without causing problems for the custom auto-scaling rules I have already set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the template code you can see it will create that action group:

```
 "parameters": {
    "actionGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue":  "autoscaleActionGroup",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name for the Action group."
      }
```

Comment: So, that definitely gives an answer to who created the group. Do you know if it is safe to remove it or do I have something else that I need to clean up first?

Comment: as far as I concern it's safe to delete. During the deletion before your final confirmation you should see a list of objects you are deleting.